# Random Session Expiration while implementing Policy based role authorization in asp.net core

Tags: c#, .net, session, asp.net-core

We have developed an ASP.NET Core Web application which is working fine both in local and server.

when implementing the **custom policy based role authorization** and If I have upload the dll code on the server, session expires before timeout & user is redirected to login page

**I don't know what makes session expiration so soon while implementing custom policy authorization.** Again my point is, Application works well with session  without implementing role based authorization.

I'm getting both session and role of user from the redis.

```
protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, RoleRequirement requirement)
    {
        RedisConnection redis = new RedisConnection();
        if (SessionId == null | SessionId == string.Empty)
        {
            context.Fail();
        }
        else
        {
            string MemberDetails = redis.GetMemberSession(SessionId);
            RedisModel SessionDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RedisModel>(Details);
            Role = SessionDetails.UserRoleLevel.ToUpper().Trim();

            switch (requirement.Roles)
            {
                case Constants.MEMBER:
                    if (Role == requirement.Roles)
                    {
                        context.Succeed(requirement);
                    }
                    break;
                case Constants.PROVIDER:
                    if (Role == requirement.Roles)
                    {
                        context.Succeed(requirement);
                    }
                    break;
                case Constants.ADMIN:
                    if (Role == requirement.Roles)
                    {
                        context.Succeed(requirement);
                    }
                    break;








    [HttpGet("nname")]
    [Authorize(Policy = "ADMIN")]
    [ServiceFilter(typeof(Filter))]
    public IActionResult NName()
    {
        ............
        ............
    }
```

Comment: What auth session expiration time do you set in code and what is the actual expiration time?

Comment: auth session expiration time is 2 hours. actual expiration time differs each time. it will expire in 5 or 10 min and so on.

Comment: Can you share some code snippets of your implementation?

Comment: I think the problem may be with IIS. but I'm not sure.